# lambdify a sympy expression that contains a Derivative of UndefinedFunction

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have several expressions of an undefined function some of which contain the corresponding (undefined) derivatives of that function. Both the function and its derivatives exist only as numerical data. I want to make functions out of my expressions and then call that function with the corresponding numerical data to numerically compute the expression. Unfortunately I have run into a problem with lambdify.

Consider the following simplified example:

```
import sympy
import numpy

# define a parameter and an unknown function on said parameter
t = sympy.Symbol('t')
s = sympy.Function('s')(t)

# a "normal" expression
a = t*s**2
print(a)
#OUT: t*s(t)**2

# an expression which contains a derivative
b = a.diff(t)
print(b)
#OUT: 2*t*s(t)*Derivative(s(t), t) + s(t)**2

# generate an arbitrary numerical input
# for demo purposes lets assume that s(t):=sin(t)
t0 = 0
s0 = numpy.sin(t0)
sd0 = numpy.cos(t0)

# labdify a
fa = sympy.lambdify([t, s], a)
va = fa(t0, s0)
print (va)
#OUT: 0

# try to lambdify b
fb = sympy.lambdify([t, s, s.diff(t)], b)  # this fails with syntax error
vb = fb(t0, s0, sd0)
print (vb)
```

Error message:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    lambda _Dummy_142,_Dummy_143,Derivative(s(t), t): (2*_Dummy_142*_Dummy_143*Derivative(_Dummy_143, _Dummy_142) + _Dummy_143**2)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Apparently the Derivative object is not resolved correctly, how can I work around that?

As an alternative to lambdify I'm also open to using theano or cython based solutions, but I have encountered similar problems with the corresponding printers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the problem originates from an incorrect/unfortunate dummification process within the lambdify function. I have written my own dummification function that I apply to the parameters as well as the expression before passing them to lambdifying.

```
def dummify_undefined_functions(expr):
    mapping = {}    

    # replace all Derivative terms
    for der in expr.atoms(sympy.Derivative):
        f_name = der.expr.func.__name__
        var_names = [var.name for var in der.variables]
        name = "d%s_d%s" % (f_name, 'd'.join(var_names))
        mapping[der] = sympy.Symbol(name)

    # replace undefined functions
    from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
    for f in expr.atoms(AppliedUndef):
        f_name = f.func.__name__
        mapping[f] = sympy.Symbol(f_name)

    return expr.subs(mapping)
```

Use like this:

```
params = [dummify_undefined_functions(x) for x in [t, s, s.diff(t)]]
expr = dummify_undefined_functions(b)
fb = sympy.lambdify(params, expr)
```

Obviously this is somewhat brittle:

- no guard against name-collisions
- perhaps not the best possible name-scheme: df_dxdy for  `Derivative(f(x,y), x, y)`
- it is assumed that all derivatives are of the form:
  `Derivative(s(t), t, ...)` with `s(t)` being an `UndefinedFunction` and `t` a `Symbol`. I have no idea what will happen if any argument to Derivative is a more complex expression. I kind of think/hope that the (automatic) simplification process will reduce any more complex derivative into an expression consisting of 'basic'  derivatives. But I certainly do not guard against it.
- largely untested (except for my specific use-cases)

Other than that it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, rather than an UndefinedFunction, you could go ahead and use the implemented_function function to tie your numerical implementation of s(t) to a symbolic function.

Then, if you are constrained to discrete numerical data defining the function whose derivative occurs in the troublesome expression, much of the time, the numerical evaluation of the derivative may come from finite differences. As an alternative, sympy can automatically replace derivative terms with finite differences, and let the resulting expression be converted to a lambda. For example:

```py
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function

# define a parameter and an unknown function on said parameter
t = sympy.Symbol('t')
s = implemented_function(Function('s'), numpy.cos)

print('A plain ol\' expression')
a = t*s(t)**2
print(a)

print('Derivative of above:')
b = a.diff(t)
print(b)

# try to lambdify b by first replacing with finite differences
dx = 0.1
bapprox = b.replace(lambda arg: arg.is_Derivative,
                    lambda arg: arg.as_finite_difference(points=dx))
print('Approximation of derivatives:')
print(bapprox)
fb = sympy.lambdify([t], bapprox)

t0 = 0.0
vb = fb(t0)
print(vb)
```

Answer (score 0):

The similar question was discussed [at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718313/define-numerical-evaluation-of-a-derivative-of-a-sympy-function)

You just need to define your own function and define its derivative as another function:

```
def f_impl(x):
    return x**2

def df_impl(x):
    return 2*x

class df(sy.Function):
    nargs = 1
    is_real = True
    _imp_ = staticmethod(df_impl)

class f(sy.Function):
    nargs = 1
    is_real = True
    _imp_ = staticmethod(f_impl)

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        return df(self.args[0])

t = sy.Symbol('t')
print f(t).diff().subs({t:0.1})

expr = f(t) + f(t).diff()
expr_real = sy.lambdify(t, expr)
print expr_real(0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not apply here. I'm deliberately using an UndefinedFunction, because the function definition is not available in closed form. Only discrete numerical data points are available. As far as I can tell, the problem originates from an incorrect/unfortunate dummification process within the lambdify function. I have written my own dummification function that I apply to the parameters as well as the expression before lambdifying it. I will post it as an anwser.

Comment: the function *f* in this case will be undefined. It will be implemented when u will try to lambdify or evaluate it numerically.

Comment: hm, so what happens if I leave out the `_imp_` parts (because I do not have them)? Will it still work?

Comment: It will. Just try something like

`class f(sympy.Function):
 pass

t = sympy.Symbol('t')
print f(0.1)
print f(t).diff()`

Comment: Ok, but this still does not solve the original problem. Try this: `fn = sympy.lambdify( f(t).diff(), f(t).diff() )`. Which is admittedly a pretty pointless example, but I would expect I to compile, which it does not.

Comment: My suggestion is a workaround. It doesn't allow you to substitute the derivative, it allows you to change substring `Derivative(s(t), t)` by another function let's say `g(t)`. After that you can use g(t) like an argument in lambdify. Another solution is the using of `subs` function:
`v = sympy.Symbol('v')(t);
b1 = b.subs({s.diff(t): v});
fb = sympy.lambdify([t, s, v], b1); `

Comment: The second option is basically what I ended up doing.