# Cannot lambdify sympy expression with derivative

Tags: python, sympy

I cannot lambdify expression that contains derivatives. Here is the minimum code that explains the problem:

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
a = sympy.Function('a')(x)
b = a**2
r = sympy.diff(b, x)
sympy.lambdify((a), b)  # works
r.evalf(subs={diff(a, x): 1, a: 2})  # works 
b_x = sympy.lambdify((diff(a, x), a), r)  # throws an error
```

The last line of code throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "<ipython-input-29-a0069a059795>", line 2, in <module>
    gx = sympy.lambdify((diff(a, x), a), r)  # gives an error   File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sympy\utilities\lambdify.py", line 434, in lambdify
    func = eval(lstr, namespace)   File "<string>", line 1
    lambda Derivative(a(x), x),_Dummy_29: (2*Derivative(_Dummy_29, x)*_Dummy_29)
                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use code formatting for errors. It works wonders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lambdify a sympy expression that contains a Derivative of UndefinedFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920641/lambdify-a-sympy-expression-that-contains-a-derivative-of-undefinedfunction)

Comment: SymPy issues [10844](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10844)  and [13753](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13753)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lambdify` attempts to replace symbolic functions with numerical equivalents and
return a function which can accept numeric values or arrays and return a number or array.

The error message

```
lambda Derivative(a(x), x),_Dummy_29: (2*Derivative(_Dummy_29, x)*_Dummy_29)
                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

shows that lambdify is trying to build a lambda function whose first argument is `Derivative(a(x), x)`. Clearly that's not going to work. We need a bare variable name instead of the symbolic expression `Derivative(a(x), x)`.

So replace `Derivative(a(x), x)` with a bare symbol, `da`:

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
a = sympy.Function('a')(x)
b = a**2
r = sympy.diff(b, x)
da = sympy.symbols('da')
b_x = sympy.lambdify((da, a), r.subs([(sympy.diff(a, x), da)]))
assert b_x(1, 2) == r.evalf(subs={sympy.diff(a, x): 1, a: 2})
# 4
```