# Derivative of manipulated spline

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I am using the `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` function from the `scipy.interpolate` library. I know that there exists a function the evaluate the derivative of the resulting spline. What I am interested in is the derivative of the log of the spline. Is there a way to calculate this directly?

Comment: Would writing it yourself using the chain rule be an option?

Comment: Yes. I don't know, why I did not think in this way. Anyhow, the question remains, if you can define a function, depending on a spline, which can be differentiated by python (analytically)? I think this is the case for splines, since the polynomial functions are easily differentiated analytically.

Comment: One could take the spline of the log of your data. Then the derivative is available directly.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the same, since on has to use the chain rule, as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FlyingTeller's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012099/flyingteller) is probably optimal: the derivative of log(f) is `f'/f` which is easy enough to implement:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
x = np.arange(1, 9)
y = np.sqrt(x)                                  # something to use as y-values
spl = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)

logder = lambda x: spl.derivative()(x)/spl(x)   # derivative of log of spline

t = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max())
plt.plot(t, logder(t))
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Constructing a spline based on the logarithm of data is also a reasonable approach, but it is not the same thing as the logarithm of the original spline.

> if you can define a function, depending on a spline, which can be differentiated by python (analytically)

Differentiating an arbitrary function analytically is out of scope for SciPy. In the above example, I had to know that the derivative of `log(x)` is `1/x`; SciPy does not know that. [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is a library for symbolic math operations such as derivatives.

It's possible to use SymPy to find the derivative of a function symbolically and then turn it, using [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html), into a callable function that SciPy or matplotlib, etc  can use.

One can also work with splines in an [entirely symbolic way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47878791) using SymPy but it's slow.